# How to setup EventBus into fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, exception, greenrobot-eventbus

I am experimenting EventBus libaray. I just registered it into Fragment and I used `@Subcride` annotation into that fragment with `public` methods but when I run the app I get exception which tells that I don't have used `@Subcribe` annotation with `public` methods in `super` class. Why do I need to declare it in `super` class? How to fix this problem
**This is my first time with EventBus**

Here is code

Fragment

```
public class SignUpFragment extends BaseFragment {
Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_up, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, layout);
    return layout;
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(String uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onSignUpFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    EventBus.getDefault().register(getActivity()); // Here comes the exception
    if (context instanceof OnSignUpFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnSignUpFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnSignUpFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(getActivity());
    mListener = null;
}
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onEvent(JSONObject response) {

    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

}

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onEvent(VolleyError error) {
    Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
}
}
```

This is the exception I get

```
10-31 11:01:46.172 9047-9047/com.aam.skillschool E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.aam.skillschool, PID: 9047
org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBusException: Subscriber class com.aam.skillschool.ui.activities.MainActivity and its super classes have no public methods with the @Subscribe annotation
at org.greenrobot.eventbus.SubscriberMethodFinder.findSubscriberMethods(SubscriberMethodFinder.java:67)
at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.register(EventBus.java:136)
at com.aam.skillschool.ui.fragments.SignUpFragment.onAttach(SignUpFragment.java:113)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1048)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.setLastIn(BackStackRecord.java:838)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.calculateFragments(BackStackRecord.java:878)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:719)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1682)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:541)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass `getActivity()` to EventBus `register()` method, pass the Fragment instead, which in this case should be `this`

Answer (score 0):

You are likely calling `EventBus.getDefault().register(this)` in your activity but do not have any methods with the `@Subscribe` annotation.

You only need to register the components that use the annotations.

Move the registration to your `Fragment`.

Comment: I am doing all this stuff in fragment since i want all this functionality in fragment

Comment: The exception states you have registered your activity as well as\instead of the fragment. If you have no @Subscrive annotations in the activity, you should not register it with the event bus

Comment: What I said was correct but on checking further, you are using OnAttach in your Fragment to register the Activity.  Please use OnPause/OnResume to register and unregister the Fragment instead.

Comment: Thanks. It was happening because of ```getActivity``` as parameter to ```register()```. I changed it to ```EventBus.getDefault().register(this)``` inside fragment and this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using sticky events (registerSticky()), because events sent this way will wait until fragment receive them. This can be helpful to metigate Fragment's lifecycle. - Activity send event at a time when fragment not ready and fragment will receive it at some point - when it inflated and ready.
For subscribing to some kind of event create public method with @Subscribe annotation.